# What's the difference between a Resource and an Embedded Resource in a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, embedded-resource

When should I use one or the other?

I'd like all of the files I use in my app (images, sound, xml file, etc.) to be inside of the .exe file so I don't deploy with a bunch of folders and files.

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

“Resource” and “Content” build actions are to access the WPF resources using the Uris. However “Embedded Resource” is for prior technologies. However both options embed the resource in assembly but “Resource” option to be used for WPF.

MSDN provides full explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-application-resource-content-and-data-files).

Comment: You're right! I set all the images in my WPF project to Resource and re-built the source. Now when I navigate to the Debug folder I cannot find the files anywhere, they must be a part of the .exe, exactly how I want it. Can't thank you enough! :)

Comment: The MSDN link is broken. Additional explanation here would be very nice.

Comment: The "new" link from November 2018 still works. :)

Answer (score 13):

A WPF resource (build action = *Resource*) leverages embedded resources as supported by the core .NET framework, but adds support for accessing the embedded resource via a [pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx):

> WPF resource files are not the same as
>   the embedded or linked type of
>   resources that can be configured using
>   the core .NET Framework support for
>   assembly resources. While WPF resource
>   files do leverage the core .NET
>   Framework embedded resource support,
>   the ability to access WPF resource
>   files using pack URIs is easier than
>   using namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

As reported by MSDN,

> Embedded resources are the best choice
>   if you have to share application
>   resource (.resx) files between
>   multiple projects. For example, if you
>   have a common resource file that
>   contains your company's logos,
>   trademark information, and such, using
>   embedded resources means you have to
>   copy only the .resx file and not the
>   associated resource data files.
>
> You cannot edit embedded resources
>   directly. If you try to edit an
>   embedded resource, you will receive a
>   message prompting you to convert the
>   item to a linked resource in order to
>   edit it. Conversion is recommended but
>   optional. You must export them, make
>   your modifications in an external
>   program, and then import them back
>   into your project.

Comment: This diesn't answer the question: what is the difference between an embedded resource and a resource? You answer only addresses Embedded Resources.

Comment: The text of the question says "When should I use one or the other?"; I think I answered to that. The questions are really two.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the reports, that helped me find more precisely where was the problem:
For me, it was the images used as **project icon** in the task bar that was built as resources and had to be built as content. All others images can be build as resources, no problem.

Hope this helps for the future.