# wpf use resource image in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to use resource image in WPF image source.I given like below,

`<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/008.jpg"/>`.

But it displays in edit page.If i run the application it not displaying in the window.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to set image property `Build Action` to `Resource`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the correct URI to the resource, and the URI depends on the method you used to add the resource this post give the details you need

[How to Embed resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419611/how-to-refer-to-embedded-resources-from-xaml)

Answer (score -1):

You can add your image to your project `Properties.Resources.Images` and then use them like that:

```
<Image Source="{x:Static Properties:Resources.YourImageName}"/>
```

**EDIT >>>>**

I've forgotten to say that you have to add this line at the top:

```
<xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:yournamespace.Properties"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am new for this.How to define properties in xaml. help me please

Comment: Your project should have it by default, just edit them.

Comment: @RanjithKumar You shouldn't do it this way. It's not how image resources are typically used in a WPF application.

Comment: Sorry @Clemens, Im just a new user of WPF and I use the images that way and it works fine. Why should I(or anyone else) use other way? and which is the other way?

Comment: @Kirenenko There are quite a lot of posts here on StackOverflow about WPF image resources. In short, add an image file to your project, set its Build Action to Resource, and access it by a [Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx).