ClassLibrary Resources in a .NET 8 project
I want to move my resources, Images and Strings.resx files, from my WPF project to a class library.
So, that a non WPF project could use the same project.
Therefor I created a new class library and move the files to the new project, made sure the Build Action for the images is Resource as it was in the WPF project.
I than noticed that my images aren't included into the *.dll file and the "resource" mechanism doesn't work.
When I do the same BUT with a class library targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and not .NET 8.0 everything works as intended.
I also noticed that when I define <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> in my .NET 8.0 class library it also works as intended.
Sadly the found work arounds don't work for me, since I don't want to target .NET Framework 4.8 and UseWpf would include undesired depencies in a non-wpf project eg. Blazor Project, when I share the class library.
I verified the missing resources with dotPeek here a screenshot, where you can see the difference between the two target frameworks:


The build system with UseWPF by defualt adds png as <EmbeddedResource/> and without as <None /> ... You need to <None Remove="path/image.png" /> and then <EmbeddedResource Include="path/image.png" /> inside <ItemGroup>

@Selvin - I believe you are mixing up Resource vs EmbeddedResource see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419611 - my cs project has the build action defined as resource <ItemGroup>         <Resource Include="Images\*.*" />     </ItemGroup> - and yes, a .NET 8 class library works with embedded resources, but than WPF doesn't know the images as it is looking for resouces

@Selvin - here a screenshot show casing my issue - https://i.sstatic.net/IYSj9lBW.png

ClassLibrary2 works either by declaring UseWPF OR changing the targetframework to net48, but both solution are undesired.

@RandRandom, do you want to create a shared class library for images to with both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 8.0

@MustafaMutasim - no, a shared library between a .NET 8 wpf project and eg. a .NET 8 blazor project - both .NET 8 BUT different types of project eg. desktop and console or desktop and web, or desktop windows and macos terminal

@MustafaMutasim - and I can't target .net framework 4.8 or use UseWPF when the class library should be used on a macOs

@RandRandom, you can, I will post my answer for WPF & MAUI you can start from it

@RandRandom this somehow works

@Selvin - as I said EmbeddedResource does indeed work in a class library BUT I can't use it in a WPF application because it won't find it, because it is looking for a resource. have another look at: https://i.sstatic.net/IYSj9lBW.png - where you can see WPF only load the image if declared as Resource and UseWPF is declared (ClassLibrary2)

@RandRandom EmbeddedResource is used for g.resx not image ... image is in resx file (in my last "image example") ... add "g.resx" of type Resource to the project remove disable code generation and delete g.Designer.cs file ... add image to resx file ... change name of image in resx

@Selvin - okay, sorry seems like it was me who wasn't looking close enough at your image, I will give it a try

ok without funky g.resx name ... you could do <ItemGroup>    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resource.resx">     <LogicalName>$(AssemblyName).g.resources</LogicalName>    </EmbeddedResource>  </ItemGroup> with normal Resource.resx

https://selvin.pl/so/ResTest.zip

@Selvin - thanks for the idea, very interesting - I can verfiy the ILSpy is showing the image, BUT dotPeek doesn't pick it up and neither does WPF - so sadly, for unknown reason, it doesn't work - do you maybe have an idea, why WPF doesn't seem to like this approach? https://i.sstatic.net/c9PmlugY.png

Is it required that the image files are embedded into the assembly? Otherwise you may set their Build Action to Content and load them from WPF by siteoforigin URIs.

the only differences are <data name="images/logo.png" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64"><value> vs <data name="images/logo.png" type="System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><value> ... this is stupid ... it works in VS but not in executable ... seems like a problem here ?

@Clemens - not really, as long as WPF can handle them, I really don't care - the only reason they are resources is because thats how you are supposed to do it

Ok, so just add the image files to your library project, set their Build Action to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Copy .... Assuming they reside in a project folder named Images, load them by <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/ImageFile.jpg"/>

lol ... it's one byte difference https://i.sstatic.net/CU7wbzur.png  in .resource file between UseWPF and my way ... this is really stupid (I modify this one byte in dll and now it shows in dotPeek)

@Clemens - attempted your idea, and it seems to work with images defined in a XAML on root level but not in subfolder eg. Controls\MyCustomControl.xaml if this MyCustomControl.xaml has an image it won't find it. After reading some documention I believe that is because it would be looking for the image at Controls\Image\abc.png instead of going to the root and search there Controls\abc.png - couldn't find the correct syntax to always look at the root, is this possible?

You mean a project folder named Controls which contains MyCustomControl with an Image with the siteoforigin Source URI? That does still work for me.

@Clemens - tried to replicate the issue in a dummy project, seems my previous diagnosis was wrong, and the issue is located else where, if I can replicate it successfully I  will come back to you

@RandRandom I finally got the solution which seems to be working

@Selvin - will have a look at it tomorrow, thanks for your dedication

btw you can target multiple frameworks  in one project <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-windows</TargetFrameworks> and  add UseWPF conditionally  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-windows' " >   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>  </PropertyGroup> then if you add PROJECT reference to blazor project it will use net-8.0 and not net8.0-windows (if you don't need this image resource in blazor)

Finally got it working...
With image logo.png in images/logo.png this csproj file should work:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <Import Project="..\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Images\Logo.png" />
        <Resource Include="Images\Logo.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>

the Microsoft.WinFX.targets will allow to compile <Resource /> elements to $(AssemblyName).g.resources in the same way as with UseWPF/UseWindowsForms BUT!!! will not add any references
The one byte difference, which I was talking in the comments, is that wpf/winforms use System.IO.PinnedBufferMemoryStream and not System.Byte[] to "serialize" image
Sample project

Thanks, for the solution seems to work just great. Just a little note, which caused an issue on my side. The order of the line <Import Project... matters. In my application I am setting <AssemblyName>MyFancyName</AssemblyName> the import line has to come AFTER changing the assembly name.
