# Prism embedded image

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, prism

I have a **module** called `xModule`. I have an **image** inside it marked as `embedded resource`.

Inside the initialization of the module I tried :

```
string stFileName = "SmallIcon.png";
string stAssembly = "xModule"; // That's the full name of the assembly
//img.BeginInit();

Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(@"/{0};component/Images/{1}", stAssembly , stFileName),
                  UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

During it's coming to the breakpoint on the `ImageSource imgSource =..` line, it seems the `ImageSource` can't find the image...

Why? What's wrong with it?

I get no errors, the assembly is referenced. I did something similar in the Xaml and it worked.
Also used : VS11, Unity

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to mark the image as "ressource" not "embedded ressource" ( WPF )

also See : [What's the difference between a Resource and an Embedded Resource in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934826/whats-the-difference-between-a-resource-and-an-embedded-resource-in-a-c-sharp-a)

Comment: Thanks giving the info, but anyway no difference in the result. I tried that also in addition with build:Content. No difference. Packed URI's give "Cannot locate resource 'images/smallicon.png'" this error and the URI I used above during a watch shows a similar result. As I said earlier this way I don't get any errors.