# Rebuild C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a project in C# and made some changes to it. When I try to rebuild using F6/Shift+F6 it keeps showing the latest version before changes. How should I compile, so that it rebuilds using the changes I made? Its so strange =(

Comment: Have you tried turning it off an on again? #it_crowd :D

Comment: Make sure you are building the correct project or solution. Make sure you are checking the correct output. Try restarting visual studio. Try saving file before build. Ensure you are changing the correct file. Ensure the file is included in build.

Comment: Have you tried to click on the *Rebuild solution* in the *Build* menu?

Comment: Try Ctrl + Shift + b

Comment: @dotctor yes, I tried everything you proposed. The thing is that I made changes in rdlc file and when I copy it inside compiled version of project that is not actual anymore, it works properly. But when I build - it doest show correct data.

Comment: @S.Akbari that was the first what I have done

Comment: When you say "...it keeps showing the latest version before changes." do you mean the file in VS is reverting to its original state, or that your changes simply aren't taking effect when you were expecting them to?

Comment: @sr28 when I received the source package it had an exe file inside bin folder already. And when I included some corrections in source it keeps compiling the exe that was from beginning. So that my changes aren't effecting final exe file.

Comment: If you click on the properties for the file, what is the build action? Is it 'Compile'?

Comment: @sr28 its an "Embedded Resource"

Comment: Can you show the code that accesses the embedded resource?

Comment: Is this a WPF app? If so, setting the Build Action to 'Resource' instead.

Comment: See this question and the answer from kiamlaluno. The 2nd paragraph might be applicable to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934826/whats-the-difference-between-a-resource-and-an-embedded-resource-in-a-c-sharp-a

Comment: try clearing the bin folder manually then build the solution again.